# Java Unzipping files from Internet Explorer shows 0 files, but works on other browsers

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have an app where a file is uploaded through the browser, and java function that unzips and goes through each file. It all works on every browser except for internet explorer.. and it's quite hard to debug because I'm not getting an error, I'm just seeing that the function

ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());

doesn't have any entries when I upload through IE, but it does in all other browsers. The size is just 0. What makes it even more confusing is that it actually did work on IE once, same file and everything just randomly in between all my failed attempts. Feel free to ask to see more of how I am doing something if necessary but as far as I can tell by debugging, all the fields are the same at this point:

```
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());
ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {

}
```

The file is the exact same location and has the same value when I run it through the debugger. any ideas why? Is it something closer to the front end even when the file is the same in both?

Here is the front end code:

```
                                <form name="detailForm" id="detailForm" method="post" action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="_blank">
                                    <td class="class" width="75">2. File:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x" value=""/>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='xsl' value='test/test2/test4.xsl'/>
                                        <fileUpload allowedExtensionList=".zip" maxFileSize="60MB"/>
                                    </td>
                                </form>
```

This calls an HttpServlet in java that does the following code.

Thanks

EDIT:

In the requests, here is a request coming from a working browser:

```
=== MimeHeaders ===
cache-control = max-age=0
accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language = en-US,en;q=0.5
content-type = multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e436f3001a
referer = http://10.0.2.2:8080/example/example/example/example.html?formType=detail&nodeID=774
upgrade-insecure-requests = 1
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19041
accept-encoding = gzip, deflate
host = 10.0.2.2:8080
content-length = 56316
connection = Keep-Alive
cookie = userID=7500; exampleID=; exampleID=0; JSESSIONID=8FD6D884B7F20F666899FD0BA335C865; example=267; exampleID=0; example=0; example=0; example=2020; example=; appName=example
```

And here is from IE:

```
=== MimeHeaders ===
accept = text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
referer = http://10.0.2.2:8080/example/example/example/example.icml?formType=detail&nodeID=774
accept-language = en-US,en;q=0.5
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
content-type = multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e41a12720132
accept-encoding = gzip, deflate
host = 10.0.2.2:8080
content-length = 802
connection = Keep-Alive
cache-control = no-cache
cookie = lang=en; example=7500; example=; example=0; JSESSIONID=DF216CFF249310F523FCC70B34A1408C; XSRF-TOKEN=0d41f9cc-1f0f-40bb-ad02-8f39ede5e7f6; example=; example=; example=0; example=parent; example=267; example=0; example=0; example=2020; example=; appName=example
```

I changed the personal names to 'example' for privacy.

Comment: How did you assign the file from input control on the web page to the file.getInputStream()? For testing purposes, did you try to pass the file path in code and check whether code works after that or not? If you did not try that then you can have a try and let us know about the results. Also, try to provide a sample code that we can try to test on our side to find the cause for the issue. The above-posted code is not enough to get an idea about the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Deepak-MSFT:
I edited the question with the front end code.

Comment: Can you please inform us, how did you access the uploaded file in your JAVA code and assign it to the file object? What result do you get if you pass the static file name in your JAVA code? Does that work in the IE browser?

Comment: Sorry for the late response - so after the html code, it hits our /upload endpoint which is a httpservlet. in the DoPost method, I noticed that the request when sent from IE (where it works) has different headers than the request sent from IE. I will update the original post with the difference. thanks

Comment: Also, it looks like only on internet explorer is when it is hitting the section of code in ApplicationFilterChain.java that says 'we fell off the end of the chain -- call the servlet instance". Any idea what this means?

Comment: Not sure why you had passed the file path in the value of hidden input. I think that The IE browser is not able to access it due to security reasons. For testing purposes, I suggest you try to use HTML file upload and try to select the file manually and then try to upload it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are referring to input type = hidden in the form for the xsl file? This is for sending the xsl file that is the result page after the file upload. (says whether it was accepted or not). What is the alternative? Or are you referring to somewhere else?

Comment: Are you referring to uploading the file using a standard form with input type = "file" instead of "hidden"?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting you to use the standard HTML File upload element and make a test whether it is working or not.